# Finding eigenvectors of $xy^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^n$, find all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the matrix $xy^\intercal$

I've already know that the eigenvalues are $0$ and $\mbox{trace}(xy^\intercal) = y^\intercal x$, but i don't know how to proceed for the eigenvectors asociated to $y^\intercal x$. For now i have

\begin{align}
xy^\intercal v = (y^\intercal x)v \iff \begin{pmatrix}x_1y_1 -y^\intercal x &x_1y_2&\cdots&x_1y_n\\x_2y_1 & x_2y_2-y^\intercal x &\cdots&x_2y_n\\\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\x_ny_1&\cdots& & x_ny_n-y^\intercal x\end{pmatrix}v = \mathbf{0}
\end{align}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Why are there zereos in the diagonal?

Comment: Because the trace of $xy^\intercal$ is an eigenvalue, so  $v$ is an eigenvector iff $xy^\intercal v = y^\intercal x v \iff (xy^\intercal - y^{\intercal}xI_n)v = 0 $, 
that eliminates the diagonal

Comment: @RaúlAstete It is not true that "that eliminates the diagonal"

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u\neq 0$ is an eigenvector. Then by definition, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ such that 
$$(xy^T)u=x(y^T u)=\lambda u$$

Notice that  $y^T u$ is a scalar (number). So that means that either $x$ and $u$ are co-linear, or $\lambda=0=y^T u$.

Conversely, it's easy to verify that $x$ itself is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $y^Tx$ (again, a number). And any vector $u$ that is orthogonal to $y$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.